# Connection problem while connecting to PostgreSQL database through JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have an IP address `192.168.218.18`
I've tried a lot of ways connecting to that server every time I'm getting a message as connection attempt failed.
For security reasons I've hidden the username and password.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.218.18:5432/manikanta?user=*****&password=*****&ssl=true";
        try {

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("connection established");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Exceptions i got

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:211)   at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)     at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.inno.demo.ConnectionJDBC.main(ConnectionJDBC.java:17) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:75)     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
>     ... 7 more

Comment: Have you verified the ping status to the above mentioned IP address?

Comment: "Ping failed". This message i'm getting even though i provided the correct details.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: yeah i've updated the question please check

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing the user and password separately, not as part of the URL:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.218.18:5432/v";
    String user = "****";
    String password = "*****";

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        System.out.println("connection established");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

See: http://zetcode.com/java/postgresql/

Comment: Still getting the same message "Connection attempt failed"

Answer (score 0):

Since pinging to the IP `192.168.218.18` (I'll refer to this as `target` system) has failed, verify and confirm one of the following:

- Your system is connected to the same network as the `target` system (i.e. Private network)
- If you have access to the `target` system, try pinging your local machine's IP from that system and check if pinging is successful from there or not
- Make sure that your/`target` system's firewall is configured to allow connections to each other

If you confirm these, I am sure you will at least have a basic idea of what and where it is going wrong. And with that your connection issue will get resolved.